# Validating length in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which is used for text field and the directive has a validation like below which should show a message when the textfield length is less than 5 characters.

```
 attrs.$observe('useNumberRegex', function( val ) {
                  scope.useNumberRegex = GenericFieldUtils.castBoolean(val, false);
                  if(scope.useNumberRegex)
                  {
                    scope.regExp = /^\d+$/;
                  }
              });
```

and the directive template URL points to html as shown below

```
      <li ng-if="editable  && (cssClass == 'text_style_filter' || cssClass == 'drp_down_style')" style="float:left;width:42%" class="{{$parent.cssClass}}">
       <input id="{{$parent.uniqueId}}" name="{{$parent.name}}" type="{{$parent.textType}}"  class="field-control {{$parent.numCssClass}}" ng-pattern="$parent.regExp" autocomplete="off"  ng-required="mandatory" ng-maxlength="{{maxLength}}" maxlength="{{maxLength}}" ng-model="$parent.value" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-blur="$parent.onBlur($parent.value)" ng-keyup="$parent.onKeyup($parent.value)" aria-label="{{$parent.ariaLabelInput}}" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" validate>
            <div ng-if="$parent.formController.submitController.attempted">
                {{$parent.regExp}}
              <span class="error-message" ng-repeat="error in errors" translate>{{error}}fdsfsdfsdf</span>
            </div>
          </li>

Can you please help me what is going wrong in displaying a message when the length is less than 5 characters long.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [ng-minlength](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) to actually validate the length of the input.
2. You could also use the regex pattern to validate the same. Instead of /^\d+$/ use /^\d{5,}$/